# Downgrading ZEND v2.2.0 to v1.11.11 on Mac using XAMPP v0.3

Tags: zend-framework, xampp

for a certain project I need to downgrade the ZEND version in my XAMPP v0.3 on a Mac from 2.2.0 to 1.11.11. Unfortunately adding the path to include_path:
include_path=".:/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/lib/php:/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/lib/Zend"
does not show any effect.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks and cheers,
Sven

Answer (score 0):

First of all the base folder for your Zend library should probably be `/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/lib/` and not `/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/lib/Zend`.

Finally it's very simple. The version of Zend depends on the content of the folder Zend **inside the library folder**. Right now I guess it is occupied by v2.2.0 and you'll have to either replace this folder with contents of v1.11.11 or use another (new) library path with a Zend folder containing the older version. Then you use this new library path in your include_path.

Note that if you have or need other folders inside this new library you'll either have to copy those folder or (sym)link those folders into the new library folder.

Comment: Hi Adrian, thank you for your answer. You are right, I need to use the path you said. But funny enough there is no folder named Zend or any like that. And I also put a Zend folder with the v 1.11.11 in but nothing changed. At least when I look in phpinfo. 
Oh and yes I did restart the server :)

Comment: @svendeswan The Zend Framework is **only** a library available at runtime and does not show up in phpinfo. Now the real question is how you are using ZF and where you currently make it available. In a regular ZF MVC application that happens in your public/index.php